# Why does the following Python generator expression work?

Tags: python, generator-expression

I'm trying to wrap my head around a common generator idiom I encounter in the wild.  I've noticed it (and used it) for a long time but never bothered to question it. An example of the idiom using a toy function:

```
def contains_vowels(string):
    vowels = set('aeiou')

    if any((char in vowels) for char in string):
        return True

    return False
```

Why does `any((char in vowels) for char in string)` work as expected?  I get that `(char in vowels)` is a generator expression, but e.g. `(char in vowels) for char in string` is not a valid generator outside of a function call.

Put another way, given that the above code is valid, why does the following code *not* work:

```
    for b in (char in vowels) for char in string:
        print b
```

(obviously, making the whole expression a generator *does* work as expected:

```
    for b in (char in vowels for char in string):
        print b
```

)

I get that it's a bit of a silly question but the answer isn't immediately intuitive to me.  Is it just a case of "because that's the way the syntax works" or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `(char in vowels)` is not a generator expression. `expression for i in seq` is a generator expression. `x in foo` is checking for containment.

Comment: I get that `x in foo` checks for containment.  I just always assumed the `()` were indicating a generator because this is the only context in which I've used this pattern, although what you're saying makes sense.  So I guess the take away is you can define generator expressions without parentheses inside a function call... but e.g., I know this doesn't work in function calls with multiple arguments.  So, a more elaborate answer would be useful.

Comment: You would also `return any(char in vowels for char in string)`, you don't need an if/else

Comment: Sure Padraic, it's just a toy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I
>   get that `(char in vowels)` is a generator expression,

Actually, it's not. The parentheses are completely superfluous in this case, since there's just a single operator `in`. When you have more operators, parentheses are used to set order of operations. `(1+2)*3 == 9`

> `(char in vowels) for char in string` is not a valid generator outside of a
>   function call.

Actually it is. Inside a function call you can skip the extra parentheses, when the generator is the only argument. So the following two lines are in effect the same.

```
any(char in vowels for char in string)
any((char in vowels for char in string))
```

Outside a function call, the generator must have parentheses.

```
(char in vowels for char in string)
```

Comment: So generator expressions inside single-parameter function calls are just a special case.  I guess I knew the answer to this question all along, but felt the implicit generator syntax was inconsistent with what I'd expect.

Comment: Yes, it's a special case.

Comment: This can be a bit hard to find in the docs if one does not [use python for functional programming](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) - search for *parentheses signalling a function call also count*.